# How can I know if the cursor in textarea is still active?

Tags: javascript, css, mootools

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7NdHM/3/

When the label is click on it shrinks the size of the text to leave space to see what is being written. Also when a user clicks outside the input region the text goes back to the original size. All of this works well. My issue is that when I click on another tab in the browser and I come back the cursor is still inside the textarea (that's good) but the label is back to normal (full size) and that is wrong.

I assume it as something to do with the use of the onBlur event, if this is the case is there some other way to get the text to full size only when the cursor is not inside the textarea?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="input">
    <label>Multiple lines and a floating label</label>
    <textarea rows="fit" placeholder aria-label="Multiple lines and a floating label" aria-invalid="false" fit></textarea>
    <div class="border-bottom">
        <div class="underline"></div>
        <div class="underlineHighlight"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="errorContainer">
      <div class="error" role="alert" aria-hidden="true"></div>
      <div class="errorIcon"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
$$('.input').addEvent('click', function(e) {
    var target = document.id(e.target),
        input = (target.match('.input'))?target:target.getParent('.input'),
        textarea = input.getChildren('textarea')[0],
        label = input.getChildren('label')[0],
        underlineHighlight = input.getChildren('.underlineHighlight')[0];

    textarea.focus();

    //if () {
        label.addClass('animate');
        underlineHighlight.addClass('animate');
    //}
});

$$('.input textarea').addEvent('blur', function(e){
    var target = document.id(e.target),
        input = target.getParent('.input'),
        textarea = input.getChildren('textarea')[0],
        label = input.getChildren('label')[0];

    label.removeClass('animate');
});
```

The CSS:

```
.input {
    height: 73px;
    width: 320px;
}

.input label {
    position: absolute;
    height: 19px;
    margin-top: 24px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

.input label.animate {
    color: #4059a9;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7) translateY(-27px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7) translateY(-27px);
    -o-transform: scale(0.7) translateY(-27px);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.7) translateY(-27px);
    transform: scale(0.7) translateY(-27px);
}

.input textarea {
    width: 320px;
    height: 19px;
    resize: none;
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    flex-direction: column;
    cursor: auto;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    outline: none;
    border: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 24px 0 0 0;
    font: inherit;
}

.input .border-bottom {
    top: 35px;
}

.input .underline {
    height: 1px;
    background: #757575;
    border-bottom-color: #757575;
}

.input .underlineHighlight {
    color: #4059a9;
    background: #4059a9;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.input .underlineHighlight.animate {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.03, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    background: #4059a9;
}

.input .errorContainer {
    height: 24px;
}
```

Here is what I am trying to reproduce with CSS3, and Mootools: http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-input (the last input).

Comment: you have blur, what's wrong with it? It fires when focus lost

Comment: window.onblur=function(){ document.activeElement.blur();  };

Comment: `blur()` fires on every "focus-lost"-event. It fires on leaving the browser-window too. The Problem is that `focus()` does not fire again if the browser-window gets it again (and places the cursor in the beforee focussed field).

The only quick and dirty solution migt be to set the focus to another object on blur. Then the user must click the textbox again and `focus()` does fire again.

Comment: But how is Google doing it? http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-input

Comment: to deal with focus, track the last input and use window.onfocus=function(){ lastInput.focus(); };

Comment: @dandavis you're on the right path. I will publish the answer soon.

Comment: Yes! I will put the explanation soon. Sorry for the time it is taking me.